# Isabelle 2017: Support for proof method definitons seems to be lacking

Tags: isabelle

Isabelle is supposed to come with Eisbach, a language for easily defining your own proof methods. The Isabelle/jEdit IDE has a link to the Eisbach User Manual, but Eisbach seems to be unavailable. The token `methods` is treated as an identifier by the IDE’s syntax checker, and auto-completion does not know about a `methods` keyword either.

How can I access Eisbach? Do method definitions have to go into special files instead of theory files? At least, I did not find anything in the Eisbach User Manual that said so.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The documentation seems to miss (at least I couldn't find a hint) that you have to import the Eisbach theory in addition to Main

```
theory My_Theory
  import
    Main
    "HOL-Eisbach.Eisbach"
begin
```

before Eisbach is available inside your theory file.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this information. In fact, the necessity of this import does not seem to be documented.

Comment: This is a serious bug in the documentation!  Thanks very much for this.  It also seems that different imports are required for different purposes.  For instance, you need to import instead `"HOL-Eisbach.Eisbach_Tools"` if you want to use the `curry` and `uncurry` attributes mentioned in section 2.6 of the Eisbach user manual.  And if you're using a base theory other than `HOL`, such as `FOL`, `ZFC`, `Sequents`, etc., then you have to instead import `"HOL-Eisbach.Eisbach_Old_Appl_Syntax"`.